# jQuery getJSON parseerror Expected ';'

Tags: jquery, json, parse-error

Using IE8, jQuery 1.6.1.min.js.

The JSON that comes from the REST service seems to be valid (atleast when I validate it on jsonlint.com)

```
{
"requestId":"1624517264",
"acknowledge":1,
"errorCode":0,
"totalResultCount":2,
"results":[
{"EmployeeCode":"007","EmployeeUno":7,"EmployeeName":"Bond, James","Location":"Unknown","Login":"JBOND"},
{"EmployeeCode":"008","EmployeeUno":8,"EmployeeName":"Bar, Foo","Location":"NYC","Login":"FBAR"}
]}
```

jQuery:

```
  $.getJSON(urlToSvc + "&callback=?", function (data) {
                   // can't get to here 
                });
```

I get a javascript error Expected ';'.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the lines before this line?  Maybe the typo is there?

Comment: do you get the same error when you use $.get(urlToSvc + "&callback=?", function (data) { //process }, 'json');

Comment: i think jquery returns `null` or something if the json is invalid anyway, so it wouldnt throw a syntax error. the error is your JS somewhere. doesn't appear to be in the snippet you gave us though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that's exactly the response from urlToSvc, then it looks like you're making a JSONP request but urlToSvc is returning plain JSON.

If you use a tool like Firebug to inspect the request that `$.getJSON()` makes, you should find that it's replacing `callback=?` with something like `callback=jQuery152012865984649397433_1306892572812`. That means jQuery expects the JSON to be returned as a parameter to a function call to `jQuery152012865984649397433_1306892572812()`.  That's how it wires up your callback function behind the scenes.

In that case, the response should look something like this (though the exact function name will change on every request, specified by the `callback` querystring parameter):

```
jQuery152012865984649397433_1306892572812('{"requestId":"1624517264","acknowledge":1,"errorCode":0,"totalResultCount":2,"results":[{"EmployeeCode":"007","EmployeeUno":7,"EmployeeName":"Bond, James","Location":"Unknown","Login":"JBOND"},{"EmployeeCode":"008","EmployeeUno":8,"EmployeeName":"Bar, Foo","Location":"NYC","Login":"FBAR"}]}')
```

Comment: Dave you're right the service is returning plain JSON.  Any ideas why it's not being returned with the callback function?

Comment: Dave you got me thinking so I started checking the WCF service web.config.  "crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled" was set to false.  Setting this to true fixed the issue I was having.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON looks valid. Consider the possibility that the traceback is imprecise and that it is, in fact, a syntax error in the callback function. Also ensure that this data is the data actually being received—if the URL is slightly off, for example, you might be trying to parse an error page. Chrome or Firebug's Network tabs are great for exactly this.